# CloudBalance example tweak

Tags: optaplanner

I've been playing with the basic CloudBalance example, and have given it input of one Computer and two Processes.  Both processes are too much to fit on the computer, so only one should go on.  However, when solving the solution (albeit with negative HardScore) is that both Processes are on the Computer.  I understand there is not actual solution for both Processes, but shouldn't the result only have one Process assigned to the Computer, and the other not assigned?  How would I need to change the setup to make that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at **Overconstrained Planning** in the docs. By default, OptaPlanner will assign all Processes, because assigning to `null` is not an option.

Comment: Thank you @GeoffreyDeSmet for your help and leadership of OptaPlanner.  I know CloudBalancing example is intended to be the most basic example, but I would consider modifying to include Overconstrained setup, since assigning Processes to a Computer that use more CpuPower than the Computer has available is not a great solution in that use case.